# How to implement reject/approve functionality with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

For example,  a model called Request, this model has a status field, status is by default "Awaiting", I want to make it possible for someone to change that through a form to "Approved" or "Rejected" I tried using some methods but they all didn't work.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: just update model with `request.status = 'Approved'` or `'Rejected' `and save it.

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: @MazenMamdouh I think following the tutorial on https://djangoproject.com will answer your questions and more how to change models via a form!

Answer (score 0):

```py
req_db = Request.objects.get(pk=1)    # get pk from form or somewhere
req_db.status = 'Approved'  # or use models.TextChoices
req_db.save()
```